# Building Spark 1.5.2 - Maven heap space issue

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, build

I am building Apache Spark with the `make-distribution.sh` script. It works fine till the `spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10` module.
My `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable is:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx15g -XX:MaxPermSize=15000M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=15000M"
```

Even though the memory assigned to Maven is very high, it still fails in the creation of `spark-streaming-mqtt-test-1.5.2.jar` jar file.

Below is the error stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.5:single (test-jar-with-dependencies) on project spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive test-jar-with-dependencies: Problem creating jar: Execution exception: Java heap space -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10
```